# WCF Test Client Error Cannot obtain Metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, net.tcp

I'm trying to run a website using IIS, but I can't get the service to work.
The service uses the protocol net.tcp and the listener is running:
[net.tcp listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mw5k.png)

The endpoint and service is correctly created:
[c# code for service and endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6T8v.png)

And here is the IIS website:
[IIS service website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg7DV.png)

Comment: If there're some tutorials you followed to publish your website? So that we may try to reproduce your issue with them.

Comment: unfortunately there isn't, but it was a pretty standard deploy, like added PortalCliente website to IIS using port 8081 and ClienteService using http 8088 and net.tcp 808. The service is running (I can access the service using the http protocol), but the net.tcp just keeps showing the error about metadata.

Comment: Please describe the exact error you receive or describe the steps to narrow down the problem. You wrote, that the listener seems to be active. Can you connect via TCP? Do you see any requests appaering in the IIS log? Does you application have some kinde of log that could show somehting? None of this is clear, so it is hard to help.